# Is Fluent call style self referencing records in Delphi possible?

Tags: delphi, types

The goal is to create a type called TURLString to be called as follows:

```
var
  newURl : TURLString;
begin

  newURL.Append('http://').Append('www.thehost.com').Append('path/on/server').Append('?');

  ...lots of app logic...

  newURL.AppendParam('name', 'value').Append('#').AppendParam('name', 'value');

  ...more params added...

  result := httpClient.Get(newURL);

end;
```

With TURLString defined like this (note its a record):

```
//from actual code used
TURLString = record
private
    FString : string;
public
    function Append(APart : string) : TURLString;
    function AppendParam(AParam, AValue : string) : TURLString;
end;

function TURLString.Append(APart: string) : TURLString;
begin
  FString := FString + APart;
  result := self;
end;

function TURLString.AppendParam(AParam, AValue: string): TURLString;
begin
  if (not Empty) then
    FString := FString + URL_AMB;
  FString := FString + AParam + '=' + AValue;
  result := self;
end;
```

When stepping through the fluid calls, the values are appended but when exiting they revert to the first string passed into the first append call and newURL is equal to 'http://' while debugging the append call you see 'http://www.thehost.com/path/on/server?name=value#name=value'.

Is this concept possible with a record?

Comment: It seems you want TStringBuilder-like behaviour, which is more compatible with Class (by-Reference) rather than Record (by-Value) semantics, except you also don't want to construct (Create) the instances. Is that it?

Comment: FWIW such an interface based on method chaining is known as a **fluent** interface

Comment: No, it is fluid because it leaks :-P

Comment: To make a fluent interface like what you show, that doesn't leak, waste time with memory-copying, and which auto-constructs itself and cleans up properly after itself, would require some kind of managed memory (gc or reffcounting), or some pretty advanced trickery. Since what you're really doing is methods on strings, I would think that ability to add a method to a string, as a level of syntactical sugar, would be close to what you want. Download the FreePascal compiler sources and let us know how far you get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a value type like a record then you need to assign the final returned result to a variable:

```
newURL := newURL.Append('http://').Append('www.thehost.com');
```

If you use a reference type like a class instance, then you can use the syntax that you used in your question.

The reference type approach treats the data type as mutable, whereas for value types you are best implementing an immutable data type.

Comment: So this keeps all the copying, but retains the result, rather than discarding it, but doesn't qualify as "fluent", right?

Comment: @Warren This is still a fluent interface.

Comment: Well, then +1 for U.  Probably this is the closest to what the OP wants that you can get. :-)

Comment: @Warren a fluent interface like this is very common with immutable data types, e.g. .net `String`.

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of the performance and memory use problem of record copy, you may use pointers as results type for your methods:

```
type
  PURLString = ^TURLString;
  TURLString = record
  private
    FString : string;
  public
    function Append(const APart : string) : PURLString;
    function AppendParam(const AParam, AValue : string) : PURLString;
  end;

function TURLString.Append(const APart: string) : PURLString;
begin
  FString := FString + APart;
  result := @self;
end;

function TURLString.AppendParam(const AParam, AValue: string): PURLString;
begin
  if FString <> '' then
    FString := FString + URL_AMB;
  FString := FString + AParam + '=' + AValue;
  result := @self;
end;
```

So you may be able to call your original TURLString just as wished:

```
newURL.Append('http://').Append('www.thehost.com').Append(...
```

And don't forget the `const` keyword for string parameters of methods.

Note that the proper way of using a pointer should have been

```
newURL.Append('http://')^.Append('www.thehost.com')^.Append(...
```

but in fact the Delphi compiler is clever enough to add the ^ sign implicitly.

With this trick, you don't have to create nor free your `newURL` instance. Note that only reference-counted parameters (string, variants, interfaces) will be initialized on the stack: integers or doubles will be pure random.

This is exactly what I used for creating some RTF content in my [SynProject](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/30/SynProject) documentation tool (at least in the first versions, now I use a class instead of a record, since I wanted to add inheritance).

Answer (score 4):

The record style creates a new, anonymous (and therefore unreachable, for you) record for each call and the `Result = self;` line **copies** the "current" record to the new one. This may not be what you want. As David says, you'll have to assign the (anonymous) end result to a record variable you declared, so you can finally access the end result.

If you use a reference type (object or interface), it will return a reference to itself, and no new object is generated (and nothing is copied). That makes a lot more sense in the fluid style.

Comment: Sometimes immutability is a desirable property. If so the value type is the winner.

Comment: The intermediate anonymous records will be immutable, but unreachable anyway. The final result, if assigned to a variable or parameter, is not immutable, AFAICT. The original record is immutable, during the function call, indeed. Hmmm... I hope I didn't misunderstand what you mean. How does one make a record immutable?

Comment: One makes it immutable by declaring all its fields to be strict private and only assigning to those fields when new records are created.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at my TPathBuilder implementation [here](http://www.soundvibe.net/blog/tpathbuilder-builds-your-path-easily/). It's main purpose is to build file paths but you can get the idea. Source code is included in the post.

Comment: Adding an open string argument array like `function Add(const Folders: array of TFileName): TPathBuilder; overload;` should have made the trick, with less record copy and memory allocations.

Comment: I don't think that this is an issue for such a simple task. I preferred simplicity and code readability over performance because it's probably impossible to notice any performance penalty using it. Optimization must be performed when it's really needed IMO.

Comment: Of course. But my point was not only about performance, but about the fact that an `array of string` will also make it easier to use: only a comma to separate items, and no method name. Fluent call style is sometimes error-prone, when it starts to be huge. I use it, but try to never abuse.

Comment: I see your point. I guess it's just a matter of taste. And I also agree that fluent interfaces should be used with care and only when they can help to make things easier and more clear.